# Hide input value by user privilege, but still submit

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where I get first privileges of the user logged in.

In my example have simplified to:

`$user_privilege = 1` the user can view/edit ALL fields

`$user_privilege = 2` the user CAN'T view/edit price fields

then the user can view/edit the form.

The problem is that if a product has these values:

```
name = "example title"
description = "example description"
price = 56
```

if I'm a user with user privileges = 1 during submit form the values are corrected update.
But if i'm a user with no price privileges, during submit the $price is not submitted and default value is empty.

What i want is, if a user with no edit price submit changes (name and description), the price must not be updated.

What is the best way to do this? I don't want to edit my actual function insert_product and edit_product (cause I have a lot of other scenario like this on my web app)...
I was think to get a solution to hide by jquery side...like using type="password" and readonly (if i've not privileges)

```
Price: <input type="<?php if ( $user_privilege == 2 ) { ?>password<?php } else { ?>text<?php } ?>" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" <?php if ( $user_privilege == 2 ) { ?>readonly<?php } ?>>
```

to still pass old value from form to php function, hiding it to the user.

Any better solution?

```
<?php

   // GET USER PRIVILEGES

   $user_privilege = get_user_privileges(); // return 1 for Admin with all permission. return 2 if not permission to views/edit PRICES


   $action = "insert";
   $id = "";
   $name = "";
   $description = "";
   $price = "";

   if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {

       $action = "edit";
       $id = $_GET['id'];
       $product = ge_product($id);
       $name = $product['Name'];
       $description = $product['Description'];
       $price = $product['Price'];
   }

   if ( isset($_POST['action']) ) {

      $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
      $description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : "";

      $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : "";

      if ( $_POST['action'] == "insert" ) {
         $id = insert_product($name, $description, $price);
      } else {
         if ( $_POST['action'] == "edit" ) {
             edit_product($id, $name, $description, $price);
         }
      }

   }

?>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
   Product name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
   <br>
   Description: <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>">
   <br>

   <?php if ( $user_privilege != 2 ) { ?>

   Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
   <br>

   <?php } ?>

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">       
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $action; ?>">
   <button type="submit"><?php echo $action; ?></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest that using javascript ( jQuery ) to hide potentially sensitive functionality is not the way to proceed - to prevent invalid updates by users of the wrong access level do the enforcement server side in php

Comment: Anything you do only client-side, is of course not a solution _at all_. You need to verify the parameters your script received on the server side. Just because you make an input field readonly, does not mean I can not _edit_ that field in my browser via dev tools, before submitting your form. (If I am even using a “browser” at all to make my requests to your site.)